# Is Ampere's law or Fraday's Law reversible for AC currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

In other words, if a time varying magnetic field induce a amount of voltage/current into a coiled wire, would generate the coiled wire that is loaded with the measured/calculated amount of induced voltage/current the same magnetic field?

My thought experiment is the following.

First thought experiment:
I have a coiled wire ($N$, diameter $D$, length $l$) that is loaded with an ac current and/or voltage ($I_a$, $V_a$). The coiled wire generates a magnetic field $B_{gen}$ at position $A$ in a distance $d$ away from the coil.

Second thought experiment:
I put a changing (time varying) magnetic field source $B_{sou}$ at $A$ and calculate the induced current and/or voltage ($I_{in}$,$V_{in}$) into the coiled wire. **But**, the changing magnetic field source equals the calculated magnetic field such that $B_{sou}=B_{gen}$.

**Question:**
Would the induced voltage/current equal the voltage/current from the first experiment such that:  $(I_{in}$,$V_{in})=(I_a, V_a)$  ?

I assume that Lorentz reciprocity is not applicable. I do not only the interchange the position of source and sink but the kind of source as well.